# Incorrect glyphicon sizes in form / .input-group / .input-group-addon inputs in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add glyphicons to form input boxes using **bootstrap 3**.

However, the glyphicons are displayed larger than the input textbox, as can be seen here:

[image: Silly large glyphicons]

The [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) says *Use `.input-group` with an `.input-group-addon` to prepend or append elements to a `.form-control`.*

As far as I can tell, I'm doing just this, but I clearly have something wrong, and can't figure out what it is.

**Markup and fiddle below:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h4>Glyphicons, why you no look nice?</h4>
    <form name="form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
            <input type="email" 
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Email" 
                name="email"/>
        </div>                
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
            <input type="password" 
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Password" 
                name="password"/>
        </div>                
    </form>
</div>
```

[Working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfQ9b/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `font-size` is being inherited from the 'jumbotron' (21px).

You'll need to explicitly set the font-size on the form or its items.

Also, once you use the glyphicon class, you'll get the `top: 1px` so you'll need to set that to 0 for the addon to line up with the input.

[Here's my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfQ9b/4/).