# Bootstrap glyphicon in button addons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

`Glyphicons` in `Bootstrap` button addons cause the button to shrink so it doesn't fit the input properly.  Standard text doesn't have this problem.

Is there a way to do this?  Here's an example:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

But changing the `button` to something like the following works fine.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">XXX</button>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391366/incorrect-glyphicon-sizes-in-form-input-group-input-group-addon-inputs-in) suggests the font size is inherited from the parent element but I don't think that applies here as it works fine with text, and changing the font-size rule doesn't help.

Comment: I have created demo [here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ALRZbQ) It work fine. Definitely there is css overriding happening in your case..

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">  
        <span class="input-group-addon">    
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>     
</div>
```